# PHP file upload using using CURL

Tags: php, curl

I am using PHP for uploading file from sever s1 to server s2 my code is:

```
// initialise the curl request
    $request = curl_init('http://myip/filepath/');

    // send a file
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt(
        $request,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        array(
          'file' => new CurlFile('photos/081452_7893637.jpg')
        ));

    // output the response
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    echo curl_exec($request);

    // close the session
    curl_close($request);
```

When I run the this script the error is:

```
The requested URL / was not found on this server.
```

But when i browse it from URL it works fine.
Could anyone help please what is wrong with my script?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// initialise the curl request
    $request = curl_init('http://myip/filepath/');


    function getFile($filename, $contentType, $postname)
{
    if (function_exists('curl_file_create')) {
        return curl_file_create($filename, $contentType, $postname);
    }
    $value = "@{$this->filename};filename=" . $postname;
    if ($contentType) {
        $value .= ';type=' . $contentType;
    }
    return $value;
}


    // send a file
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt(
        $request,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        array(
          'file' =>getFile('photos/081452_7893637.jpg','image/jpeg','dummy.jpg')
        ));

    // output the response
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    echo curl_exec($request);

    // close the session
    curl_close($request);
```